# Ask confirmation when page closing with unsubmitted form

Tags: javascript, symfony

I have a form, and I would like to ask confirmation when the page is closed by the user before submit the values. I already tried the script described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624843/dont-ask-confirm-if-user-submit-the-form)  but it seems not to work: the userSubmitted value figure like always true, and the pop-up doesn't appear.

The code in my template is:

```
 <script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
if(!userSubmitted)
    return 'Are you sure that you want to leave this page?';};
</script>
```

the code in my controller is:

```
$userSubmitted=false;
//...

$form->handleRequest($request);
       if ($form->isValid()) {
        $userSubmitted=true;

//...
return $this->render('DefaultBundle::formupload.html.twig', array(
       'form' => $form->createView(), 'userSubmitted->$userSubmitted
       )); 
//...
```

Comment: Something like `onbeforeunload = function(){ return prompt("Are you sure?"); }`

Comment: onbeforeunload  works, if you does not put your code we cannot help you

Comment: You might be looking for this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606496/show-message-box-ext-window-beforeclose-event

Comment: where is your code ..? coz the given example is enough for you..

Comment: just answered the same question 10 minutes ago, for more specific questions please put your code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709936/alert-with-multiple-options/22710191#22710191

Comment: @giammin edited the question with the code.

Comment: @radia edited the question with the code.

Answer (score 5):

```
var warn_on_unload = false; //default false 


$('input,textarea,select').on('change', function () { 
  //making true when user types in , or select
    warn_on_unload = true;
});

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
//warns user if not saving form and closing or browsing other page
    if(warn_on_unload)
    {
        return confirm('Leaving this page will cause any unsaved data to be lost.');
    }

});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't understand. I'm using it in a template rendered with a twig engine.

Comment: Add `return confirm 'Leaving...'` in there (it's in the suggested edits). The confirm keyword is missing.

Comment: @Zlatko without 'confirm'  its working fine , for me when I use confirm it doesn't work ! Is that working for you with confirm ?

Comment: @CodingAnt Pheraps I found the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.  Twig  uses by default the "output escaping", in order to avoid XSS attacks. But it pheraps nullify also the $ character. Could it be? Infact it take the function only if I put it as window.onbeforeunload, and not with the character $.

Comment: @user3455230 so is your code up and running now mate ?

Comment: @CodingAnt no. Not yet.

Comment: just use return 'Leaving this page will cause any unsaved data to be lost.'; **without confirm**